# Who is resolving the name?

Tags: networking, bash, dns, ping, dig

If I do this:

```
» dig m1.dcos

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> m1.dcos
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61257
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m1.dcos.                       IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 10 14:50:50 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36
```

And this:

```
» ping m1.dcos
PING m1.dcos (192.168.65.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from m1.dcos (192.168.65.90): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.213 ms
64 bytes from m1.dcos (192.168.65.90): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.224 ms
^C
--- m1.dcos ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.213/0.218/0.224/0.015 ms
```

Some questions:

1. Why don't I get and ANSWER section for `dig`
2. Why is ping resolving the address, and `dig` does not?
3. How can I resolve the address (on the command line, `bash` on Ubuntu) like ping `does`?

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't get an answer because the DNS server at `127.0.0.1` does not have a record for `m1.dcos`. That's what `NXDOMAIN` means (Non-eXistant DOMAIN).
2. Ping uses nsswitch instead of direct DNS (like `dig` does). It might be resolving the hostname from somewhere else (LDAP, NIS or local files).
3. You can use the `host` command.

Comment: Apparently `host` just uses what’s in `/etc/resolv.conf`, so it’ll only query DNS, like `dig`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, `host` also fetches information from `/etc/hosts `, with the following `nsswitch.conf` entry: `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`